# PWA audio player for android

Tags: progressive-web-apps

We are making audio player in PWA for android.

should be able to save mp3 file locally.

What are the best places to manage mp3 files and list of files in json.

File Api has limited support, therefore I am not sure if I  should go with this idea.

The file should be downloadable locally on mobile and should be able to play offline.

Answer (score 3):

With PWAs you can define which assets to cache locally and made available offline, therefore it might be a good approach to provide the offline feature to mobile and desktop users.

Google created a [PWA Media Player project](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sample-media-pwa). Maybe you can have a look at it and get some inspiration for your project.

I wrote a [series of article about different PWA aspects](https://dev.to/paco_ita/a-gentle-introduction-to-progressive-web-apps-step-1-24da), if you are interested in deepening the topic.

Comment: don;'t know dust.. was looking for a simple approach . .and simpler docs